Model deforming improperly
I created a human model using the human generator addon and tried to retarget an animation from mixamo to the HG rig, but I just can't figure it out. There's something wrong with the shoulder region.
I used AutoRig Pro to retarget the animation to the HG model and reset the rest pose from an A pose to a T pose.
All throughout the process, I didn't encounter any problems. But the result of the retargeting looks off. When I remove cloth from the HG model, everything looks fine, but if I add cloth the cloth that replaces the overlapping body mesh deforms incorrectly.
Here's without the cloth

and here's with the cloth

I've looked at the weights and tried fiddling with them, but nothing I do works.
I've attached a link to the blend file. I do appreciate the help


Can you give us a bit more info in the actual post to help debug your issue? There should be more that we can do to help you than literally download the blendfile and just try to figure out what "something wrong with the shoulder region" actually entails. Post screenshots/gifs of the error, write out/ show examples of what you're aiming for etc. Not only does it make our life easier but it will make your actually solving your issue more likely.

Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload images or gifs, along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Thanks for clarifying this for me. I've made corrections to my initial post and added what I think should be all the steps I took during the process. Looking forward to a solution. Thanks
